# MySQL Column to Key-Value Pair Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m having some trouble to transform a single-row MySQL query result into key-value row pairs.

Here´s my query result on table wp_users:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users where ID = 28

**ID | login |  nickname** ...
28 | abcde |  mynickname
```

I´d like to transform it to:

```
**KeyHeader | ValueHeader**
ID       | 28
login | abcde
nickname | mynickname
...
```

This is in order UNION ALL this query to a previous query and stack it with other key value pairs.
I get that I can simply write this to get single key-value pairs separately:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT "ID", ID FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 28
UNION ALL
SELECT "login", login FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 28
UNION ALL
SELECT "nickname", nickname FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 28
```

But is there a cleaner way to make my wp_users query into this key-value form without having to hardcode and repeat myself for every column?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You can write a stored procedure that gets all the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and constructs the query dynamically.

Comment: MySql 8.0 supports LATERAL.

Comment: @Serg What you say is technically a true statement, but it's not clear how it is related to the question above. How would LATERAL be used to do what the OP wants to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent versions of MySQL support [`lateral join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html)s.  You could express this as:

```
select x.*
from wp_users u cross join lateral
     (select 'id' as key, u.id as value union all
      select 'login' as key, u.login as value union all
      select 'nickname' as key, u.nickname as value
     ) x;
```

You can generate the code for the columns using a spreadsheet or another SQL query, if that is cumbersome.

This also has the advantage of reading the original table only once.

That said, you probably want another column in the result set to identify the entity (the structure you want is probably an entity-attribute-value structure).

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother! Was not aware of this type of join.